# Loading Sharepoint files into Bigquery

Tags: sharepoint, google-bigquery, bq

I want to create a BigQuery table out of some files that are present in our organizations secured space of sharepoint.
The files will be added on weekly basis and I need to setup a pipeline that I can use to ingest data in bigquery. I have been following manual process of loading the files by downloading the files and uploading to gcs bucket but that doesnt seems feasible anymore.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe one possible solution could be using [`BQ Client`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html).  Currently, I set up a pipeline to read daily updated excel sheets and load them directly to BigQuery using `BQ Client` and [`pygsheets`](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: @Amit can you please post the solution that helped you out here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write python code to read the SharePoint API.
Create a Data proc job with could scheduler this way you can achieve your problem