# Any connectors to allow data stored in Microsfot sharepoint list to Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sharepoint, google-bigquery, sharepoint-list

Right now, I got some data that stored in Microsoft Sharepoint List as below

[image]

And I would like those data stored back to Google Cloud Bigquery.

Does there any existed pipline or connector to do this thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Crazy, Could you check the comment of this [stack case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338146/loading-sharepoint-files-into-bigquery), also check this [documentation](https://pipes.datavirtuality.com/connectors/integrate/microsoft-sharepoint-online-connector/google-bigquery/#:~:text=Pipes%20allows%20you%20to%20automatically,BigQuery%20on%20your%20defined%20schedule) and let me know if this helped you or not ?